# Loop through results of last command (wtmp)?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am struggling to find any reference on how to loop through the wtmp file. If I use the **last** command I get all the information that I need, but I want to work with in in a script. I've read that I can use **awk** to do this, but I don't know how to loop through each line that is shown. For example the following results:

```
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
```

What I need is to loop through each line, and get username, hostname, and time of login. So, in this case, username.x.y.z, hostname.x.y.z and Tue Feb 9 10:22.

How do I get this?

Comment: Does your `last` command not list more info between username and hostname? The format of `last` output is not well-designed for scripting. If you have `utmpdump` that might be more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `command` output be

```
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
username.x.y.z        hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb  9 10:22 - 10:22  (00:00)
```

then

```
command | awk '{NF=6;print}'
```

gives output

```
username.x.y.z hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb 9 10:22
username.x.y.z hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb 9 10:22
username.x.y.z hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb 9 10:22
username.x.y.z hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb 9 10:22
username.x.y.z hostname.x.y.z Tue Feb 9 10:22
```

Explanation: there is implicit loop in GNU `AWK` therefore single action is applied to all lines, I set number of field (`NF`) to 6 therefore prompting GNU `AWK` to get 6 first fields, then I `print` them. Observe that default field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) are used, therefore this code needs following to hold true: there is never space inside any field AND fields are separated by one-or-more whitespace characters AND there is 6 or more fields in each row. If you want to know more about GNU `AWK` built-in variables then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: this will break if there is whitespace in fields (the output of `last` on my machine can have whitespace in at least the `ut_line` and `ut_host` fields). It may be safer to work with fixed width fields but even that may not work reliably as the date formats that are output are not consistent

Comment: Thank you, I used a part, (not nf=6) and got it to work!